# initrd.img and vmlinuz how to install the one just 1 lower than the higer? Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, apt, grub2, kernel

I have not updated my Ubuntu 18.04 Since long days.
today i have run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`
after this i did `sudo update-grub` which gave below result.

```
pratap@i7-6550U:~$ sudo update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found theme: /boot/grub/themes/TestTheme/theme.txt
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-42-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-42-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-34-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-34-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Found Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (18.04) on /dev/sda10
Found Ubuntu 18.10 (18.10) on /dev/sda8
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
pratap@i7-6550U:~$
```

i found that 4.15.0-42 is higher, and 34 is very far from 42,
i want to keep 41 as the secondary choice next to 42.

Is it possible to install it replacing 34 in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the old kernel with

```
sudo apt remove linux-headers-4.15.0-34:amd64 linux-headers-4.15.0-34-generic:amd64 linux-modules-4.15.0-34-generic:amd64 linux-image-4.15.0-34-generic:amd64
```

To install another kernel (e.g. 4.15.0-39) run

```
 sudo apt install linux-headers-4.15.0-39:amd64 linux-headers-4.15.0-39-generic:amd64 linux-modules-4.15.0-39-generic:amd64 linux-image-4.15.0-39-generic:amd64
```

Note that this packages will be marked as manaully installed, so they will not get removed with `sudo apt autoremove`. You can mark them as automatically installed with

```
sudo apt-mark auto linux-headers-4.15.0-39:amd64 linux-headers-4.15.0-39-generic:amd64 linux-modules-4.15.0-39-generic:amd64 linux-image-4.15.0-39-generic:amd64
```

You may want to check with `Synaptic` which kernel versions are available. You can also use the command `apt list linux-headers-*-generic` to see which kernel versions are available:

```
mook@mookpc:~$ apt list linux-headers-*-generic
Listing... Done
linux-headers-4.15.0-20-generic/bionic 4.15.0-20.21 amd64
linux-headers-4.15.0-22-generic/bionic-updates,bionic-security 4.15.0-22.24 amd64
linux-headers-4.15.0-23-generic/bionic-updates,bionic-security 4.15.0-23.25 amd64
linux-headers-4.15.0-24-generic/bionic-updates,bionic-security 4.15.0-24.26 amd64
linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic/bionic-updates,bionic-security 4.15.0-29.31 amd64
linux-headers-4.15.0-30-generic/bionic-updates,bionic-security 4.15.0-30.32 amd64
linux-headers-4.15.0-32-generic/bionic-updates,bionic-security 4.15.0-32.35 amd64
linux-headers-4.15.0-33-generic/bionic-updates,bionic-security 4.15.0-33.36 amd64
linux-headers-4.15.0-34-generic/bionic-updates,bionic-security 4.15.0-34.37 amd64
linux-headers-4.15.0-36-generic/bionic-updates,bionic-security 4.15.0-36.39 amd64
linux-headers-4.15.0-38-generic/bionic-updates 4.15.0-38.41 amd64
linux-headers-4.15.0-39-generic/bionic-updates,bionic-security 4.15.0-39.42 amd64
```

For me version 4.15.0-39 is still the recent version in the official repository, I don't know where you got version 4.15.0-42, probably you have proposed packages enabled in `Software Updater`.

Comment: In Synaptic use the search function and search for `kernel` or `linux-headers-generic`, that should give you sufficient information.

Comment: Yes, it's pretty useful to find out anything about available packages. Please see also my edit, you can also use apt to find out which kernels are available.